# In Vue-watch, echarts.resize() doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, echarts

In vue, I watched the width(cause of side menu flex), when the value changes, it will invoke resize method, but it doesn't work.

```
watch: {
    mainWidth: {
      handler (val) {
        console.log('watch: ', val)
          this.chart.resize()
      }
    }
  }
```

I can catch the value change, but the chart doesn't resize

I tried nextTick and setTimeout, but failed. I expect the resize method will work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are implementing echart whether you are using npm vue package or core js, but if the problem is related to container change listener
you can use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

Bind the listener to the container that holding the echart and call resize within it.

Something like this:

```
const container = document.getElementById("containerId");

var chart = echarts.init(container);

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  chart.resize();  
});

resizeObserver.observe(container)
```